# Is there a way to hide/mask/obfuscate the password in a Nightwatch test?

Tags: nightwatch.js

I'm creating Nightwatch tests that login to our web portal.  Currently, the password is in clear text in the Nightwatch test ...

```
browser.setValue('#password', 'myPas$word1')
```

Is there a way to hide or mask or at least obfuscate the password?

Answer (score 0):

Nightwatch by default do not support anything that helps your problem.

One thing you can do is use environmental variables to pass it during run time.

You can create a environment variable as 'MY_PWD' or something in your system and use it as below.

```
browser.setValue('#password', process.env.MY_PWD)
```